# No visible @interface for MFMEssageComposeViewcontroller declares the selector 'setToRecipients'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sms, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

Friends,there is something fishy here now and then,

I am working with MFMessagecomposeviewcontroller and really worked out well,after sometime when i am writing code i am getting this error newly

No visible @interface for MFMEssageComposeViewcontroller declares the selector 'setToRecipients'

I know this is the method that is existing in this class but i don't know why it is not allowing me to do.

please send your response soon.

Comment: yah i got the mistake where it is.I posted the answer,i appreciate your timely response

Answer (score 0):

Friends,its my mistake,that method name is setRecipients.for MFMessageComposeViewController

and its setToRecipients for MFMessageComposeViewController.

MFMessageComposeViewController*message=[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc]init];

[con setRecipients:somearray];//for message

MFMailComposeViewController*message=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];

[con setToRecipients:somearray];//for mail

But,on internet there are some many places where they mention setToRecipients and i tried with that,please be careful with method names.

Thanks.